# Export SQL database to mdb file (MS Access) using Java-Spring

Tags: java, sql, spring, ms-access

I'm trying to export a SQL database to a mdb file, through my java-spring application, but I haven't found anything really useful.

The idea is to call a controller endpoint, which calls my service. There, I need to:

1. Execute a SQL query and get the result set
2. Return the mdb file, which contains just a new database with the table generated from the result set above
3. Download the ms-access file from the browser

How can this be achieved?
Thanks in advance

I haven't really tried many things, as the only way I seem to achieve this is by creating the mdb file directly in the client's computer and then opening a connection to execute a insert with the data, and that is not what I want to do. I'm stuck here

Comment: Why don't you create the Access file on server side? E.g. you can use [UCanAccess](https://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) to connect to an Access DB via Java.

Comment: @vanje I tried what you suggested and it's looking good, I'll post an update when it's done